# How can I know that users rate my app actually on google store?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to make my game like this.

If player go through whole lite levels, then pop up menu is shown.

Player can select "Rate App" button for getting some useful items.

But if player doesn`t rate my app actually on Google Play Store, he will get nothing.

How can I know that player rates my app actually?

As I know, it is very difficult to know that correctly.

Any good way or idea?

Let me know the correct way, Please.....

Thanks.

Comment: stores don't allow that, for instance it would open doors to ganking the system. ie giving players who vote 5 stars bonus content as incentive to vote 5 stars in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Reviews & ratings doesn't get updated instantly, it takes time. You cannot get to know if the user has rated your app or not. You can just assume that the user would have rated the app after he/she hits your "Rate App" button. So once the user presses rate the button you can save a preference to check if he or she has rated. Obviously it's not efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I have another question.

Comment: You can vote up for a thank you and share the link of your new question.